# How to pass parent id inside child form without nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a standard belongs to and has many relationship between `Post` and `Comment`.

```
#post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
end

#comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post, dependent: :destroy
end

#routes.rb
resources :posts
resources :comments, except: [:index, :show]
```

Now inside my post show view I call
`%li= link_to 'New comment', new_comment_path(post_id: @post.id)` which provides the post id for the `new` action to be used with comment form. The url looks as following:
`/comments/new?post_id=6`.

Now here's where problem happens. After filling up the form the post_id is not carried over nor sent to the create action and I get an error that `Post must exist`. Looking at the `params` hash, there's obviously no `post_id` to be found.

**Question**: How do I pass the `post_id` and build new `Comment`? Is there another way besides nested routes? If so, Is it desirable (or Rails way)? Should I perhaps create a custom route and override `create` given from `resources` method?

I'm aware that I could fix this problem by using nested routes, since then the create action will have proper url to find the parent id (`Post`). However, I'm trying to understand inner workings of Rails more throughly so I'm trying to find alternative ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `:post_id` ussing a `hidden_field_tag` in the comments form:

```
<%= form_with model: @comment do |form| %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :post_id, value: params[:post_id] %>

  <%# ... other comment fields %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now in your controller's *create* action the `:post_id` is passed as an attribute of `:comment`

```
# comments_controller.rb

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

See [hidden_field() API documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field) for more examples.

Comment: It worked! Do you know of any other way of achieving this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way, but I think the best solution is to use a nested route as you describe since a `Comment` must always be associated with a `Post`.